# Deploying Django project using mod_wsgi and virtualenv

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, virtualenv

Trying to deploy a Django 1.4 project using mod_wsgi and virtualenv, i'm running into a 500. The Apache error_log reveals:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=30452): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/path/to/project/site-packages/projectapp/wsgi.py'.
[...] Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]   File "/path/to/project/env/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
[...]     self.load_middleware()
[...]   File "/path/to/project/env/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[...]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[...] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware projectapp.content.middleware: "cannot import name SomeModel"
```

From the error message i would expect that this is some kind of a path issue. However, when the offending middleware is removed from the Django settings, the site launches just fine, and there are other modules loaded from `projectapp.content`, `SomeModel` is also loaded in this case, otherwise the whole site wouldn't be able to run.

The import error raised doesn't come directly from the middleware, as it doesn't import the model. `SomeModel` is defined in a speparate app which is actually checked out into the src directory of the virtualenv. But the directory containing this app is also in the path.

The wsgi.py file i'm using:

```
import os
import sys

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/project/env/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/')
# The module inside the following directory
# defines SomeModel from the error message
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/project/env/myenv/src/some-app/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/project/site-packages/')

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'projectapp.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Printing `sys.path` after inserting the module paths shows everything in the expected order, `/path/to/project/site-packages/` is listed first and `/path/to/project/env/myenv/src/some-app/` (which defines `SomeModel`) second.

I've also tried a different variant, based on the example from the mod_wsgi docs:

```
import os
import sys
import site

ALLDIRS = [
    '/path/to/project/site-packages/',
    '/path/to/project/env/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/',
    '/path/to/project/env/myenv/src/some-app/',
]

# Remember original sys.path
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

# Add each new site-packages directory
for directory in ALLDIRS:
    site.addsitedir(directory)

# Reorder sys.path so new directories are at the front
new_sys_path = []
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path

#activate_this = '/path/to/project/env/myenv/bin/activate_this.py'
#execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'projectapp.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The error logged by Apache is exactly the same.

I have to add that the middleware is loaded just fine when i'm running the development server on the same machine, so i have no idea what's going wrong. Is there a way to get a better traceback from mod_wsgi?

**EDIT:**

Fogot to mention that i'm using mod_wsgi in daemon mode. Here are the relevant parts from my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess foo user=foo threads=10 umask=0002
    WSGIProcessGroup foo
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/site-packages/projectapp/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after hours of debugging this turned out to be a race condition caused by the middleware. The middleware i'm using is similiar to the `FlatpageFallbackMiddleware` from Django contrib and actually the import of the view caused the problem.

```
from projectapp.content.views import generic_content_detail
class ContentFallbackMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        [...]
```

Moving the import statement inside the `process_response` method solved the problem for me:

```
class ContentFallbackMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        from projectapp.content.views import generic_content_detail
        [...]
```

Comment: same problem please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739969/wsgi-for-virtualenv-not-working