# wsgi for virtualenv not working

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I'm using bitnami Django stack. 
WSGI works fine when not using virtualenv

However I installed virtualenv in root using `sudo apt-get install` and now WSGI does not work for virtualenv projects

my apache conf file is

```
Alias /static "/opt/bitnami/apps/live/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"

<Directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/live/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib'>
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /search "/opt/bitnami/apps/run/live_cybrhome.wsgi"

<Directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/run'>
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

my wsgi file is

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/apps/live')
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/apps/live/cybrhome')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'cybrhome.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The apache log is:

> mod_wsgi (pid=4070): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
>   '/opt/bitnami/apps/run/live_cybrhome.wsgi'.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 187, in **call**
>
> self.load_middleware()
>
> File
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 45, in load_middleware
>
> mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
>
> File
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py",
>   line 31, in import_by_path
>
> error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
>
> ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not
>   define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is new in Django 1.7. Presumably you have an older version of Django installed in your virtualenv.

Comment: Can you confirm this with `pip freeze` make sure its not picking up the native version.